# R - cowplot: arrange png image and ggplot, using plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am trying to arrange a png image and a ggplot object side by side using `plot_grid` from cowplot package:

```
library(cowplot)
library(tableHTML)

sg <- data.frame(start = c(0,5,10), 
                 end = c(10,20,30),
                 duration = c(10,15,20), 
                 row.names = c("A","B","C"))

p1 <- ggplot(sg)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=start, y=row_number(start), xend=end, yend=row_number(start)), 
               size = 3) +
  scale_y_reverse(labels = NULL) +
  labs(y = "", x = "") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1/5)

sg %>%
  tableHTML() %>%
  add_theme("scientific") %>%
  tableHTML_to_image(file = "image2.png", zoom = 2)

p2 <- ggdraw() + draw_image("image2.png", scale = 0.7)

plot_grid(p2, p1, ncol = 2, scale = c(0.9,1), rel_widths = c(1, 2))
```

However, in the resulting plot I find it difficult to arrange the two plots as required.

[image: see here]

Ideally, I would like the lower border of the table image to be in line with the x-axis of the graph. I would also like the two items to be closer to each other.

I have tried modifying the scale of plot p2, the zoom argument in the `tableHTML_to_image` command, or the scale, rel_widths, align and axis arguments within the `plot_grid` command, but none of it really gets me closer to the desired output.

I also read here: 
[Insert Image/PNG ggplot2 - Cowplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852428/insert-image-png-ggplot2-cowplot)
but that's only for the adding an image inside an existing plot, not beside it.

While `plot_grid` works fine when arranging two ggplots, I can't get it right with an image and a ggplot.